# Quotient of Pascal's triangles rows

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let $P_n$ denote the product of all numbers in the $n$th row of pascals triangle (for the first row $n=0$). So,
$$
P_n =  {n \choose 0}  {n \choose 1} ...  {n \choose n-1}  {n \choose n}
$$
For example,
$$
P_3 = 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 3\cdot 1 = 9
$$
I tried to find an expression for $P_{n+1}/P_n$ but I think it's wrong:
$$
\frac{P_{n+1}}{P_n} = \frac{(n+1)! (n+1)! ... (n+1)! (n+1)!}{(n+1)! n! ... n! (n+1)!} \cdot \frac{n!(n-1)!... (n-1)! n!}{n! n! ...n! n!}
$$ By simplifying a bit
$$
\frac{P_{n+1}}{P_n} = \frac{ \left[ (n+1)! \right]^{n+2}}{\left[ (n+1)! \right]^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\left[ n! \right]^{n+1}}
$$
(The $n$th row in pascals triangle has $n+1$ elements).

We then obtain
$$
\frac{P_{n+1}}{P_n} = \frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}
$$
which is wrong. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: The final result is correct. Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @user Oh. I tried plugging in some values but for some reason I never got it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way:
$$\frac {\prod_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac {(n+1)!}{k! (n+1-k)!}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac {(n)!}{k! (n-k)!}}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac {n+1}{n-k+1}=\frac {(n+1)^n}{n!}
$$
should assure you that your result is correct.